# onLocationChanged() not being called

Tags: android, gps, location

I know this question has been asked, but I can't get it to work.

This code goes on to the request location section. I know the settings right now are poor choice, but I'm just trying to get results I'm not concerned about phone battery right now. I can see in the Eclipse debugger that

```
"libloc" - "Latitude: XXXXX"    
"libloc" - "Longitude: XXXX"    
"libloc" - "Accuracy: 27000"
```

Which means that the GPS is working. But I can't get the actual location because none of the methods in the `LocationListener` is firing.

```
    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    Location loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if(loc==null){      
        String provider = null;
        
        if ( lm.isProviderEnabled( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER ) ) {
            provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "GPS not available", 3000).show();
            if(lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
                provider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Provider Not available", 3000).show();
            }
        }
        
        if(provider != null) {
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 0, 0, locationListener);
        }
        
    } else {
        Latitude = loc.getLatitude();
        Longitude = loc.getLongitude();
    }
```

This is my Location Listener object which is declared a bit below the top code. **None** of these methods are being called (hence the Log.d functions so I can add breakpoints, but nothing is being called within this listener).

```
double Latitude         = 0.0;
double Longitude        = 0.0;

LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener(){
    
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Latitude = location.getLatitude();
        Longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) { Log.d("GPS", "HEY THERE"); }
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) { Log.d("GPS", "HEY THERE"); }       
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        Log.d("GPS", "HEY THERE");
        
    }

};
```

Additional information, from comments:

> This is not the case. loc =
> lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER); is always
> returning null. – Overload119 50 mins ago
>
> What happens when you step through the rest of your code within the IF
> statement? – Jack 44 mins ago
>
> I eventually get to this line: lm.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 0,
> 0, locationListener); Then in the debugger console message I can see
> Latitude, Longitude, Accuracy showing -- and its showing repeatedly,
> so I'm assuming that the GPS has been activated and its getting the
> location. The problem is the locationListener is not firing any of its
> methods. – Overload119 41 mins ago
>
> And I looked at the link, my code is the same. – Overload119 41 mins
> ago        What is the value of provider at that point? – Jack 30 mins
> ago
>
> The value of the provider is "gps" – Overload119 15 mins ago
> Can
> you set some breakpoints in onLocationChanged to see when/if it is
> firing? If you have already done this, after running your application
> it may take a few seconds after registering the listener for it to
> fire. Move your phone around some and wait. At some point it should
> fire repeatedly. – Jack 12 mins ago
>
> imm.io/8vXb Here is a screenshot
> -- the debugger shows that the GPS is working (note that this event
> pops up over and over again). I already had breaks point on
> onLocationChanged() -- it never reaches it even after waiting for an
> extended period of time. The latitude/longitude it returns is always
> the same as well. – Overload119 39 secs ago edit
>
> I've also tried calling
> lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER); via a button,
> and click it after the console messages show that a latitude/longitude
> were received. -- the Location returned by the method is null though.
> – Overload119 0 secs ago edit

Comment: solved? same problem! seems that we both recycle the same code snippet, which is not correct.

Comment: @Overload119, omg! I got the same case what you got here. So how is the solutions?

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing that your `Location loc` is always being set by `getLastKnownLocation()`, therefore your if statement never evaluates to `true`. Have you debugged to see exactly what happens at:

```
Location loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if(loc==null){ ... }
```

?

From what I understand you should use `getLastKnownLocation()` only to get an initial location, and then register your listener for tracking.

[Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html) is a great link with all the information you need.

Comment: This is not the case. loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER); is always returning null.

Comment: What happens when you step through the rest of your code within the IF statement?

Comment: I eventually get to this line: lm.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 0, 0, locationListener); Then in the debugger console message I can see Latitude, Longitude, Accuracy showing -- and its showing repeatedly, so I'm assuming that the GPS has been activated and its getting the location. The problem is the locationListener is not firing any of its methods.

Comment: The value of the provider is "gps"

Comment: Can you set some breakpoints in onLocationChanged to see when/if it is firing? If you have already done this, after running your application it may take a few seconds after registering the listener for it to fire. Move your phone around some and wait. At some point it should fire repeatedly.

Comment: http://imm.io/8vXb Here is a screenshot -- the debugger shows that the GPS is working (note that this event pops up over and over again). I already had breaks point on onLocationChanged() -- it never reaches it even after waiting for an extended period of time. The latitude/longitude it returns is always the same as well.

Comment: I've also tried calling lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER); via a button, and click it after the console messages show that a latitude/longitude were received. -- the Location returned by the method is null though.

Comment: Have you noticed the little satellite indicator on your top status bar? Does it look like its "moving" or trying to get a fix? Or is it "fixed" and solid? I noticed your $GSV string has no data, which means you don't have a valid fix (I believe).

Comment: You must have declared the locationListener referred to in requestLocationUpdates somewhere up above that line in order for it to compile - maybe as a class member? Then it can't be the same thing as the instantiation lower down. Why don't you just declare your activity with 'implements LocationListener' and use the auto-generated method that this will produce

Comment: Agree - just let your class implement LocationListener and add the methods to your overall class.

Comment: lm.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 0, 0, this); This is now being called. I've implemented LocationListener into the overall class. I get the same thing, with onLocationChanged never executing -- the Satellite on the status bar on the phone is blinking green lights. It looks like it's 'working'. Can you go into more detail about $GSV? http://www.screencast-o-matic.com/watch/cXjODN3ki Here is a video which shows the problem

Comment: I see it's a real phone. Firstly I'd try getting rid of the lastknownlocation code whilst you narrow down the problem. Then I'd try it on the emulator, sending position via the DDMS perspective. Then I'd put a Toast in the onLocationChanged, load the app on the phone and take it outside for a walk where you can get a good satellite fix.